# ARGV always failing through regex match

Tags: ruby, regex, digits

I have a program that I'm making that is going to untar spreadsheets out of a large tarball. It will do this by being provided a number through `ARGV[0]`, it will then run through a list of text files that correspond to the large tarball formerly mentioned, once it finds the text file, it can find the correct tarball to extract from...

However, I have it set up to where it has to check the numbers given though `ARGV` before it will run a search using this: `/^\d{4,7}/`
Problem is that it keeps defaulting to this: `USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>`

I'm a little confused as to why it would do that? Can anybody explain to me what is happening here..?

I've also tried:

- `/\A\d{7}\z/`
- `/\d{7}/`

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems/package'
require 'fileutils'
require 'zlib'

class ArchiveManager

  attr_accessor :folio_num

  def initialize(folio_num)
    @folio_num = folio_num
  end

  def num_check
    if folio_num =~ /^\d{4,7}/
      search_for_spreadsheet
    else
      puts <<-EOF

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

      EOF
    end
  end

  def search_for_spreadsheet
    location = FileUtils.chdir("path/to/file")
    location
    digits = `grep -lr #{folio_num}.ods *.txt`
    file_name = digits.match(/\d+/).to_s
    puts file_name
  end
end
#/2715015
test = ArchiveManager.new(ARGV[0])
test.num_check
```

Example:

```
[]$ ruby unarchive_ss 2715015

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

[]$ 
[]$ ruby unarchive_ss 271501 

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

[]$ 
[]$ ruby unarchive_ss 1111111

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

[]$ ruby unarchive_ss 111    

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

[]$
```

Comment: Have you tried using Rubular?

Comment: @Ekult3k Yes that's where I got the three `regex`'s.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your code works as expected on my machine.

Comment: @Jordan I'm so confused then...? It just posts the digits correct?

Comment: @TheTinMan If you take it off hold, I figured out the problem and I can answer my own question?

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem is in the regex in `num_check`:

```
if folio_num =~ /^\d{4,7}/
```

Testing that pattern shows a hole:

```
'123'[/^\d{4,7}/]      # => nil
'1234'[/^\d{4,7}/]     # => "1234"
'1234567'[/^\d{4,7}/]  # => "1234567"
'12345678'[/^\d{4,7}/] # => "1234567"
```

You'll get a "true" for any number longer than you expect.

A simple fix is:

```
'12345678'[/^\d{4,7}$/] # => nil
```

Just add `$` to catch the end of the line.